# How to use js.erb in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have tried everything I can find to use a js.erb file, because I need to use ruby along with my js.

I know it is not the code, because I have the same thing in application.js, and it works fine.

Model: topics

I've tried adding topics.js.erb to views/topics/
I've tried a partial _index.js.erb, and rendering it - I see it loading, but it is not executing.

In both files, I have :

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    console.log('something');
})
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Check you topics controller action and make sure you do respond with js as by default your respond is html! Here we go: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html! Your respond should be something like this: respond_with do |format| format.js format.html end. You can also check your console (rails with running server) where you should see something like rendering topics#index in js format..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand your question now. You have some index action in controller, `index.html.erb` view and `index.js.erb` and you want to run javascript from `index.js.erb` after rendering `index.html.erb`. It won't work, `js.erb` views are used for something else. To run your javascript code only when index action is rendered you can just put this javascript code inside `index.html.erb` view. Or you can put this code in your `application.js` file and add additional conditions, so it will run only for index action.

There is no Rails way solution to this, but you can try something like this:

index.html.erb:

```
# ... your code here

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.railsView = "controller_name#index";
</script>
```

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.railsView == "controller_name#index") {
    console.log("something");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a file called index.js.erb saved in my topics view. What else do I need to do, just to have the console log something on rendering the page? It is still not connecting

Comment: @gwalshington Now I get what you mean. I changed my answer.

Comment: What are js.erb files used for? My end goal is to have both js and ruby in the same file. For example, I want to define current_user and know if they have already favorited a topic, and them them asynchronously unfavorite/favorite on the index page. This is already done via ruby, but the page reloads with each action. Would this not be the use of a js.erb?